# Coppeliasim: External call to simCallScriptFunction failed ('function_name'): error in script function

Tags: python, simulation, robotics

I ran into a problem in CoppeliaSim. I need to use a separate function in python threaded child script. The function needs to be called from gui by pressing the button, but an error occurs when it is pressed.

My code

```
#python

def sysCall_thread():
    # e.g. non-synchronized loop:
        sim.setThreadAutomaticSwitch(True)
        global joint_Y
        global joint_X
        global joint_Z
        joint_Y = sim.getObject('./joint_Y')
        joint_X = sim.getObject('./joint_X')
        joint_Z = sim.getObject('./joint_Z')

        xml = '''<ui title="xxxx" closeable="false" placement="relative" position="600,400" >
                    <button id="1" text="Z+" checkable="true" on-click="zPlus"/>
                    <button id="2" text="Z-" checkable="true" on-click="zMinus"/>
                    <button id="3" text="Y+" checkable="true" on-click="yPlus"/>
                    <button id="4" text="Y-" checkable="true" on-click="yMinus"/>
                    <button id="5" text="X+" checkable="true" on-click="xPlus"/>
                    <button id="6" text="X-" checkable="true" on-click="xMinus"/>
                    <button id="7" text="A+" checkable="true" on-click="Aplus"/>
            </ui>'''
            
        ui=simUI.create(xml)
        simUI.setTitle(ui,'Controller')
    
    

def zPlus(ui, id):
    print(joint_Z)
    pass
```

Error:

```
[/Link_base@childScript:error] ?: script execution was terminated externally.
[CoppeliaSim:error] External call to simCallScriptFunction failed ('zPlus'): error in script function.
```

Please help the newbie.